# Does Eclipse have "Syntax Aware Selection" feature?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Does Eclipse have *Syntax aware selection*, something similar to <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> in Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is called "Select Enclosing Element" in Eclipse, and the default key binding is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>.

(You can change the key binding in Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys.)

Didn't know this myself before, so thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but i think you are looking for the 'Content Assist' functionality.

If its *Content Assist*, then you can invoke it by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: Krish: No, this is different.  First time, the key combo selects to word, next time the line, then the block enclosed by the immediate paranthesis, next time the larger block, then the function etc.